# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'stateText.length')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-places-autocomplete, react-google-maps-api

I am using `react-native-google-places-autocomplete` for a filter menu on a project. While I am inputting text into the `<GooglePlacesAutocomplete/>` object I want to track the text input with a state variable called 'address'. To do that I used a predefined function `preProcess` (ideally I would use `onChangeText`, but `<GooglePlacesAutocomplete/>` does not support it). Fortunately the state variable does update when input text is changed; however, after it updates, I receive a `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'stateText.length')`. I've read every blog and stack overflow chain dealing with similar errors and haven't found why this error pops up with my specific application. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {View, Text} from "react-native";
import Screen from "../../../../components/Screen";
import styles from "./LocationStyles";
import colors from "../../../../config/colors";

import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";
import Geocoder from "react-native-geocoding";
import SuggestionRow from "./SuggestionRow";

function LocationScreen(props) {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");

  Geocoder.init("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", { language: "en" });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`address is ${address}`);
  }, [address]);

  return (
    <Screen style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 25 }}>
        <Text style={{ height: 25, fontSize: 14 }}>Street*</Text>
        <View style={{ height: 100, position: "relative", zIndex: 10 }}>
          <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            preProcess={(value) => setAddress(value)}
            minLength={5}
            debounce={200}
            enablePoweredByContainer={false}
            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
              Geocoder.from(data.description)
                .then((json) => {
                  var location = json.results[0].geometry.location;
                })
                .catch((error) => console.warn(error));
                setAddress(`${data.terms[0].value} ${data.terms[1].value}`);
            }}
            styles={{
              textInputContainer: {
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderRadius: 10,
                overflow: "hidden",
                paddingTop: 3,
                borderColor: colors.transparentPrimary,
                height: 45,
              },
              textInput: {
                height: 38,
                color: colors.black,
                fontSize: 14,
              },
            }}
            query={{
              key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
              language: "en",
              types: "address",
              fields: "geometry",
              components: "country:us",
            }}
            renderRow={(item) => <SuggestionRow item={item} />}
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={{ color: colors.medium, fontSize: 10, marginTop: -50 }}>
          e.g. 100 Larch Ave
        </Text>
      </View>
    </Screen>
  );
}

export default LocationScreen;
```

Comment: Probably second setAddress maybe some issues, chekc if data.terms exists then update state. Write to console look at what's happening too

Comment: did you try `getAddressText` method?

Comment: Thank you both! I didn't even consider using useRef. This is my solution: ```const addressRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    addressRef.current?.setAddressText(address);
  }, [addressRef]);```